# Pandas document manipulation k to 1000

Tags: python, pandas

Is there a simple way to convert a dataframe that has data formatted in k to thousands?

Ex. `10k -> 10,000`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given this is how the dataframe looks like

```
data:
  index values
    0   10k
    1   11k
```

you could do

```
data['values'].str.replace('k','000')
```

Which gives you

```
0    10000
1    11000
```

Comment: beware things like `10.1k` with this approach

Comment: Good point. In that case you could do data['values'].str.replace('k',''").astype(float)*1000

Answer (score 3):

Here is a bit more generic approach:

```
In [24]: df
Out[24]:
     a      b
0  aaa    111
1  bbb  12.5K
2  ccc  0.03M

In [25]: mp = {'K':' * 10**3', 'M':' * 10**6'}

In [26]: df['c'] = pd.eval(df.b.replace(mp.keys(), mp.values(), regex=True).str.replace(r'[^\d\.\*]+',''))

In [27]: df
Out[27]:
     a      b      c
0  aaa    111    111
1  bbb  12.5K  12500
2  ccc  0.03M  30000
```

Explanation:

```
In [28]: df.b.replace(mp.keys(), mp.values(), regex=True)
Out[28]:
0             111
1    12.5 * 10**3
2    0.03 * 10**6
Name: b, dtype: object
```